# How to match internal links with Regex?

Tags: regex

I am trying to build a regex which will match every line which doesn't contain the word "`stylesheet`" in it, and has an "`a href`" which has a value NOT starting with `http` or `www`.

This is how far I got, but it doesn't seem to do what I want:

```
grep -rin "href=\"\/*\/*\/|^((?!stylesheet).)*$" *.html
```

The goal is that this would be caught:

```
<a href="/api_supplier/">
<a href="/other-internal-link/abc/">
```

but this wouldn't:

```
<a href="http://github.com/">
<a href="www.github.com/index.html">
<a href="/other-internal-link/test/" rel="stylesheet">
```

---

The ultimate goal of mine is to append "`index.html`" at the end of every internal link, so they would look like this:

```
<a href="/api_supplier/index.html">
<a href="/other-internal-link/abc/index.html">
```

Comment: Can you please give an example of line with stylesheet in it

Comment: You might want to get a look to parser for this job

Comment: Sure, added. Thank you

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex is a hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239)
HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.

Comment: @Toto Well, in the general case of course true; for this specific use case of course totally doable (because we can exclude pathological cases with "href=" in a value etc.).

Answer (score 0):

This regex may do the job :

```
^(.*a href)((?!http|www|stylesheet).)*$
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with all flavors of regexes. For example grep would work on single lines anyway so I assume the `^` and `$` anchors would be redundant (and consequently the `.*` following the `^`). Do you need them e.g. in Perl?

Comment: This doesn't work with: `<a rel="stylesheet" href="/other-internal-link/test/">`

Comment: I think you are right about the usefulness of ^ and $ when using grep but the .* would still be mandatory in my opinion. It's here to catch anything before "a href" which may be nothing else than a simple "<".
Unfortunately, I don't know anything about Perl so I couldn't help you here but they are still useful in many situations when you handle multiline strings for example when you are looking for a specific pattern per line.

Comment: @Toto Hum, what do you mean ? He doesn't want lines with stylesheet in it so it will be ignored as expected, right ?

Comment: No it will not. You are testing absence of `steelesheet`  **only after** `href`

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Edit, I think ^ and $ are always needed in this case, even when using grep which work on single lines because we want to match from the beginning to the end of the line and we need to tell that with the regex. Maybe someone could confirm because i am not 100% sure.

Comment: @Toto only after "a href" which makes a huge difference

Answer (score 0):

A perl way that append `index.html` to the right urls:

```
~cat file.txt 
<a href="/api_supplier/">
<a href="/other-internal-link/abc/">

<a href="http://github.com/">
<a href="www.github.com/index.html">
<a href="/other-internal-link/test/" rel="stylesheet">
```

---

```
~perl -ape 's~^(?!.*stylesheet).*?\bhref="/[^"]+\K~index.html~' file.txt 
<a href="/api_supplier/index.html">
<a href="/other-internal-link/abc/index.html">

<a href="http://github.com/">
<a href="www.github.com/index.html">
<a href="/other-internal-link/test/" rel="stylesheet">
```

---

If you want to do the replacement in-place, use the `-i` option:

```
perl -i -ape 's~^(?!.*stylesheet).*?\bhref="/[^"]+\K~index.html~' file.txt
```

Comment: That's really great, thanks for that. How to modify this to make it an inline change?